# Why isn' t high order polynomial a good fit?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Let's say I have a set of data points $(x_i,y_i), i=1,2,...,N$, and I want to approximate it using a polynomial $p(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i$ with a least squares fit (so $n<N$).

I know that the coefficient $R^2$ is a measure for goodness of fit. But as I increase the order $n$ of the polynomial $p$, $R^2$ approaches $1$. (In the extreme case when $n=N$ the fit is an interpolation with $R^2=1$.)

But a high order polynomial fit is likely an unphysical result and doesn't describe the population well. So is there a mathematical characteristic or coefficient or model that describes and explains this?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting

Comment: "a high order polynomial fit is likely an unphysical result and doesn't describe the population well": I don't agree, every smooth function is well approximated by its Taylor polynomial. For instance, it works very well for an exponential growth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you might be looking for is the Akaike information criterion. It takes the number of parameters and the maximised value of the liklihood function to produce a number; the AIC says the model which produces the minimum value is preferred. Essentially it rewards well-fitting but penalises use of extra parameters.

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion

Comment: Yes, the information theory background of AIC is enlightening. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Why you use R^2 for the goodness of fit, why not just use Mean Square Error or Root Mean Square Error? Higher order polynomials are prone to local fluctuations, what you can do is to use regularization to reduce the artifacts, e.g., you can add a penalty term to address the second order derivation of the high order polynomial.